# How to set background image texture after tracked found in Vuforia ImageTarget?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am developing AR application with Unity3D and Vuforia. I am using Vuforia ImageTarget tracking. I want to set background behind ImageTarget and it's Object after track found. How to set background image texture after tracked found in Vuforia ImageTarget?
Example : [I want background here this link](https://www.facebook.com/yamashiro.ar/videos/904203129614841/)

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to be able to do that with Vuforia. You could certainly do the leaves falling, but you'd have to do some masking to get them to go behind the target object. There's a depth mask shader, put it on a 3D representation of the real world object in the 3D space near the target. The trees above like in the video are not possible: that app has runtime spacial awareness that lets it approximate the target's position even when it is off screen once detected: last I checked, Vuforia does not have that feature.

Comment: @Draco18s ! If Vuforia cannot do it. Which AR sdk can do it? Do you have any solution for do it?

Comment: Looks like bpgeck is m ore current than I am.  But to answer your question: no, I was not aware of any available AR package that did.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is possible using a new feature of Vuforia called [Extended Tracking](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking). Select your `ImageTarget` and in the Inspector check the `Extended Tracking` box in the `Image Target Behavior` script like so:

[image]

Go to 8:10 of this video to see a demonstration of Extended Tracking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTm8kkCCNO4

**Edit:** The spaceship is moving in the video because the video filmer put a movement script on it.

However, there are some things to be aware of when you use Extended Tracking. The first is that your literal room you are doing this in needs to look somewhat unique--you can't be surrounded by white walls and be using a white table. Also, the room you are in must be static--there should be no movement in the background. Finally, it likely won't be as smooth as that Chinese beer commercial. They definitely are using some smoothing script so you don't realize the trees are moving.