# How to set position of 3D model on center AR Camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

My application using Unity And Vuforia. I want set position of 3D model of tracked found target to center Screen and AR Camera after track lost. I mean that I want to show lost Image target on center position.

Comment: You should make sure to accept your other answers that helped you. You ignored many of these. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706706/how-to-set-background-image-texture-after-tracked-found-in-vuforia-imagetarget http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686984/how-to-keep-tracked-image-target-model-object-after-tracking-lost http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36685553/how-to-keep-grid-view-scroll-position-after-fragment-pop-back-stack

Answer (score 0):

```
   void centerGameObject(GameObject gameOBJToCenter, Camera cameraToCenterOBjectTo, float zOffset = 2.6f)
    {
        gameOBJToCenter.transform.position = cameraToCenterOBjectTo.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, cameraToCenterOBjectTo.nearClipPlane + zOffset));
    }
```

Then you can call it with

```
centerGameObject(gameOBJ, Camera.main);
```

The default `zoffset`(2.6f) should work but you can change it by supplying the third parameter.

```
centerGameObject(gameOBJ, Camera.main, 6f);
```

Comment: @Sopheak I am assuming you also want your object to not disappear. In that case see my answer here on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36686984/how-to-keep-tracked-image-target-model-object-after-tracking-lost/36687578#36687578